# Error: undeclared field: 'captures' for type nre.RegexMatch

Tags: regex, nim-lang

I'm trying to match a given string with `nre`:

```
from nre import findIter, re

const sourceString = """
39
00:04:01,116 --> 00:04:01,783
Attrape.
"""
let srtRex = re"\d+\R\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\R(\w+)"

for m in findIter(sourceString, srtRex, 0):
  echo(m.captures[0])
```

This doesn't compile though, it fails with `Error: undeclared field: 'captures' for type nre.RegexMatch [declared in /usr/local/Cellar/nim/1.2.6/nim/lib/impure/nre.nim(149, 3)]`.

This is weird, because if I do `echo(m)`, I get the raw strings, so the match itself worked fine. It's only this field I can't access. And that is weird, because [in this issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/12267#issuecomment-536126100) the (working) example code is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing whole modules is idiomatic in Nim, and leads to ambiguities rarely, thanks to a strong type system. see https://narimiran.github.io/2019/07/01/nim-import.html for a great rundown on why Nim doesn't share Python's import issues.

However, here's how to do what you want to do, even if it's not idiomatic Nim:

You're using more than just `re` and `findIter`, you also use the proc `captures`, and the `[]` proc, so your import line needs to be:

```
from nre import findIter, re, captures, `[]`
```

or, for complete namespace separation, but quite ugly, you can:

```
from nre import nil
let srtRex = nre.re"\d+\R\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\R(\w+)"

for m in nre.findIter(sourceString, srtRex, 0):
  echo(nre.`[]`(nre.captures(m),0))
```

Comment: thanks for enlightening me :) Too bad this seems to be necessary for the language to work, would have preferred it like in python.

Comment: it's not "necessary" for the language to work, importing whole modules works just fine.  do read the blogpost i linked for a great exploration of why Nim is not like Python.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the imports. It works with `import nre` instead of `from nre import findIter, re`. But why? I want to keep my namespace clean!

Comment: note that Nim does not suffer from the same problems as Python. In nim it is idiomatic to import the whole module. See: https://narimiran.github.io/2019/07/01/nim-import.html

Comment: @pietroppeter i should have linked that from the start, edited my answer to answer in general rather than the specific.

Comment: yeah, that article by Miran is my go to resource in these cases :)